# Escaping postgres password

Tags: postgresql, shell, hashicorp-boundary

I need to escape my password in my pod. How can I do that? This password is being replaced with an environment variable, which is used on other platforms as well. So I can't replace it with the encoded version. Instead, I want to be able to encode it here somehow or do this escaping thing with bash scripting. Any ideas?

```
Unable to connect to the database at "postgresql://<username>:];,#]G),;@localhost:5432/database?sslmode=disable"
```

Password: `];,#]G),;`

Encoded version: `%5D%3B%2C%23%5DG)%2C%3B`

How can we get this done without touching the environment variable?

To be more specific, I'm using postgres url in my Hashicorp boundary set up.

`boundary database init  -config /boundary/boundary-config.hcl`

Config file (`/boundary/boundary-config.hcl`)

```
controller {
  name = "example-controller"
  description = "An example controller"
  database {
    url = "postgresql://<username>:<password>@10.0.0.1:5432/<database_name>"
    max_open_connections = 5
  }
}
```

https://www.boundaryproject.io/docs/oss/installing/postgres

Comment: You should show some code so that we have an idea what you are doing. Tag relevamt software.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sure just added more info on that. Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Thanks. Which environment variable are you talking about?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The password is injected with Hashicorp Vault. `postgresql://{{ .Data.username }}:{{ .Data.password }}@{{ .Data.address }}:5432/mydatabase?sslmode=disable`. As not everyone may be familiar with Vault, I didn't want to provide too much details. All i want to do is, just escaping this password in bash script so I can get this working the way I wanted

Comment: If you don't want to add these details, perhaps reproduce the problem with a `bash` script, then it can be answered like that.